# Why are model predictions not updating in tensorflow (python)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I built a tensorflow graph according to a few different resources online and am trying to fit a curve to `y=x^2`.  I am using two hidden layers with 25 and 10 neurons respectively.  The code completes, but the cost function never reduces and the ultimate chart of `x_test` to `preds` is clearly wrong.  I've looked at lots of different resources and some O'reilly books, and I can't for the life of me figure out where I'm going wrong.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

````
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

tf.reset_default_graph()
# Create Data 
X_range = np.arange(-50,50,0.1)
Y_range = (X_range ** 2)

data = pd.DataFrame({"x": X_range, "y":Y_range})
x = data['x'].values.reshape(1000,1)
y = data['y'].values.reshape(1000,)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y, test_size = .30, random_state = 42)

c_t = []

# Create NNModel function
def neural_net_model(x_data, input_dim):
    # Build the First Layer
    W_1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([input_dim, 25]))
    b_1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([25]))
    layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x_data, W_1), b_1)
    layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)

    # Build the Second Layer
    W_2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([25, 10]))
    b_2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
    layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, W_2), b_2)
    layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(layer_2)

    # Build output
    W_output = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([10, 1]))
    b_output = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))
    output = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_2, W_output), b_output)

    return output

xs = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, name="xs")
ys = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, name='ys')

output = neural_net_model(xs, 1)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(output-ys))
train = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(.005).minimize(cost)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    # Run for 100 Epochs
    for i in range(100):
        for j in range(x_train.shape[0]):
            sess.run(train, feed_dict={xs: x_train[j].reshape(1,1), ys: y_train[j]})

        if i % 10 == 0:
            c_t.append(sess.run(cost, feed_dict={xs:x_train, ys:y_train}))
            print('Epoch :',i,'Cost :',c_t[-1])

    pred = sess.run(output, feed_dict={xs: x_test})

    print("cost: ", sess.run(cost, feed_dict={xs: x_train, ys: y_train}))

    plt.scatter(x_test,y_test,label="Original Data")
    plt.scatter(x_test,pred,label="Predicted Data")
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    plt.ylabel('value')
    plt.xlabel('x_data')
    plt.title('model_fit')
    plt.show()```
````

Comment: plus you're running the training for more than 100*700 epoch

Comment: I asked a friend who uses Neural Nets a lot for work.  We were not able to solve it using Tensorflow interestingly enough.  We did make some improvements by adding nodes (25 was not nearly enough) and using Leaky_relu as the activation function as well as the Adam Optimizer instead of the GradientDescent

However, using Pytorch, it can easily be solved (and much faster).  Truthfully I'm shocked that it was so difficult in Tensorflow and so easy in Pytorch

Comment: check my answer now, i think i find the solution. U need to normalize the data. this is what i learnt today

Answer (score 0):

I was just playing with a model then i remembered this problem
the issue was Y_range is so big in some point, so for tensorflow in order to run some calculation the memory will exceed and the value will be `inf` 
for that you need to normalize the data with `mean` equal to 0 and `std` equal to one

add

```
# Create Data 
X_range = np.arange(-50,50,0.1)
Y_range = (X_range ** 2)

def normalizor(x):
  mean=x.mean()
  std=x.std()
  return  (x-mean)/std
X_range=normalizor(X_range)
Y_range=normalizor(Y_range)
```

plus change the optimizer from GradientDiscent to Adam

```
train = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(.005).minimize(cost)
```

Comment: I appreciate the feedback.  The plt.scatter was just to see my predictions vs. the actual data.  As four `output - ys` being negative, squaring a negative value will give a positive value, so I'm not sure how that would affect the minimization of the cost function.

As for training for 100*700 epoch, it's only 100 epoch, with 700 samples per epoch.  The script finishes in approx a minute